# Как настроить ширину owlCarousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

Помогите настроить ширину owlCarousel, стараюсь сделать чтобы ширина была меньше, как можно этого добиться ?
Скриншот представлен ниже.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme first-slider" id="main-slider">
        <div class="item ramen-slider">
            <p>Рамен</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item ramen-slider">
            <p>Сухари</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item ramen-slider">
            <p>Кляр</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item ramen-slider">
            <p>Кляр</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item ramen-slider">
            <p>Кляр</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#main-slider').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    items: 3,
    dots: false,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 6000,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    onInitialized: function(){
        $('.main-wrap').css({'visibility': 'visible','height': 'auto'});
    },
});
```

[image: Слайдер]

Comment: $('.main-wrap').css({'visibility': 'visible','height': 'auto'}); если сюда добавить : 'width':'70%'?

Comment: @Horchynskyi то в таком случае, отображаются только 2 блока, мне необходимо чтобы отображалось три блока.

Comment: вам надо чтобы блоки появлялись и исчезали там где кнопки?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да т.е, ширину между блоками сделать поменьше, и помещались внутри блока со стрелками.

Comment: надо покопаться у них в документации ну я нашел Item Margin
попробуйте в 
onInitialized:
добавить 
$('.item').css({'margin-right': '10px'});

Comment: [тут](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/merge.html) показанно как делать с маленьким отступом